# Am little bit confused with how VirtualBox works

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am having this confusion from long time.Once u created a virtual hard disk(installed Ubuntu on OS X) using VirtualBox and say your host OS is mac and virtual OS is Ubuntu, if I plugged in the USB is it going to detect on both the OS and also is it possible to drag the files from one OS to another and vice-versa.

The reason behind this question is I am novice in this section so I don't want take risk as I have only 4GB of ram, though I have seen lot of videos but all tells how to install the OS using VirtualBox but nobody showed the performance and other stuff.What I mean was whether does it lag if I use both the OS at a time.

Can I use any version of Ubuntu on Virtual machine or in other words any particular version installed causes any issue with the Mac OS(Mavericks).

I think the above question is clear to all.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please what is the question? I do not see any.

Answer (score 1):

- USB Drive will only be seen by one OS at the time (Mavericks or Ubuntu, not both).
- If you only have 4GB RAM total, give the Ubuntu VM 1GB of RAM, but make sure to disable fancy window animations and transitions. Also, pick a plain color background as that will also help.

Comment: So how can I make my USB drive seen on Ubuntu while using it.And how to change the same for the my Host OS.

Comment: check out this article. seems to cover everything you're asking: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The USB stick will be visible by only one operating system at a time. When you plug it in, it is seen only by the host (Mac in your case), but you can transfer control to the guest (Ubuntu, in your case), and then, if you wish, back to the host, and so on and on, as you like. But alway one at a time.
2. It is the *shared folders* which are simultaneously available to both OSes (Operating systems).
3. The degree of sluggishness of your pc depends on the power of your hardware, and the kind of task assigned to each OS. In general, the effect is quite negligible, and may become a nuisance only in the case of very heavy work on either machine, provided you have decent hardware.
4. No guest will cause issues with the host. This is the whle of virtualization, to harmonize their interaction.

Comment: how to transfer control to the guest OS.

Comment: @rak First of all, you must have Guest Additions installed. Then you can transfer USB transfer: 1) while the VM is running, by clicking on Devices -> USB Devices, choose the USB device you are interested in. 2) Before starting the VM, by select the device you want in the filed USB deices, which will appear in your VM configuration panel after the installation of the Guest Additions.